# font awesome icon not showing in cake php

Tags: php, css, cakephp, font-awesome

i have download font-awesome-4.2.0 and load it into my cake php project.
corresponding font-awesome files and stored into below folders:

```
CSS files:
\app\webroot\css\font-awesome.min.css
\app\webroot\css\font-awesome.css
Font files:
app\webroot\fonts\
LESS Files:
app\webroot\less\
SCSS Files:
app\webroot\scss
```

I have call the font awesome CSS files in my ctp file like:

```
echo $this->Html->css('font-awesome.min');
echo $this->Html->css('font-awesome');
```

Now want to show a icon into my ctp file like:

```
<div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>                                   
</div>
```

But the icon not showing. any help?

Comment: for font-awesome you needs to add fonts too, check path of font files like eot , it should be ../fonts/FONTNAME in css

Answer (score 1):

Use this CDN in the Default file of Cakephp using link tag

https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.